# How do I translate MapBox GL JS GPS coordinates into SWEREF 99 TM ones?

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, coordinates, convert, mapbox-gl-js

I have to deal with this: https://minkarta.lantmateriet.se/?e=493056&n=6795776&z=3&profile=karta&background=1&boundaries=false

This is a URL which uses "e" and "n" in the "SWEREF 99 TM" GPS format.

But I have standard MapBox GL JS GPS coordinates, in the variables "longitude" and "latitude". I guess it's the WSG-84 or something. Which most map systems use.

If I simply put those coordinates for "e" and "n" (either way), it goes to the completely wrong place on the map.

How do I translate them properly so they make sense to that map system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Library proj4.js (http://proj4js.org/) is usually used for coordinated transformation in JS. To use it one needs CRS definition, which can be easily found on [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/) site.

SWEREF 99 TM coordinate system has CRS code `EPSG:3006`, proj4 definition string is `"+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"`.

JS code to convert `[lon, lat]` coordinate `[14.8704033, 61.2961005]` to projected Swedish coordinates could then look something like:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3006","+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
var epsg3006 = proj4("EPSG:3006");

var projCoords = proj4(epsg3006,[14.8704033, 61.2961005]);
```

If you have just a few coordinates to convert you can use epsg.io site for that: https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3006

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates like 61°51'41.2"N 12° 42'52.9"E in your link are Degrees Minutes Seconds instead of Decimal Degrees. To get Decimal Degrees you would convert like this: 61+51/60+41.2/3600.

Comment: I don't understand that calculation. They are just integers. Not like you display them. What's the actual "algorithm"?

Comment: 61°51'41.2"N is in degrees minutes seconds format and would be converted to decimal degrees by 61°+51'/60+41.2"/3600.

Comment: I do not see such coordinates in the link. Where did you get your degrees? What I see are metric coordinates in EPSG:3006 at location https://epsg.io/map#srs=3006&x=493056&y=6795776&z=2&layer=streets. EDIT: Ok, I understand now, you clicked the map on the website.